# Show annotation on MKMapView based on user location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I've problem with Objective C at the moment with developing something special.

So - after the MKMapView is initialized and the users position is shown, I would like to implement a method to show annotations which are next to users position. I've stored all necessary points in an SQLite database in a special table. I've two fields - namely `lon`and `lat`- I think it's clear what is meant by that.

Has anybody an idea how to show JUST those annotations which are visible at the screen to be as performant as possible. After the user scrolls the map - it should call the method again to look up in database wether there are also other points which need to be shown...

Thank you very much in advance for your help,

kind regards,

Dominik

Comment: I was able to receive what I needed. Thank you `nevan` and `deanWombourne` for your helpful inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do a few things.

1) Get the center of your map - use the centerCoordinate property of your MKMapView

2) Ask your database for all items within a certain distance from the center of the map.

3) Display them

It's (2) that's the tricky one - you need a method that will return all items near to the lat lng you have.

[This link](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71) has a handy implementation of how to do that :)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your link! I think my solution will base on that :). Will post again when I'm clear how to solve all of it.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

If you're using iOS4, the mapview behaviour has changed so that it automatically saves memory by only creating the annotations which are in the visible view.

Secondly, in the same way that you can create a tableview with thousands of cells and still have it scroll smoothly, the annotations offscreen don't affect the performance that much. You should be keeping your annotations very small so they don't consume much memory. The annotation views are the ones that take up the memory.

Your problem is going to come when the user zooms out and there are too many annotation views visible at the same time. When you're zoomed in, you don't need to worry too much about off-screen annotations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I'm using iOS 4 - so that is an advantage so far :)). But I need a method which shows for example the nearest four points to the users position and recenter everything based on that region. So I've to do a little bit of math I guess...

Comment: The easiest thing to do is loop through your points, convert each to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and use the `distanceFromLocation` method to find the distance. Keep the four smallest distances. Or search for Haversine formula to make your own. Dean's link is the one I used.